# Imprimir tablas en formulario Php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Pues bien, sucede que al intentar mostrar la tabla "cliente" en mi formulario php este no se genera, el problema viene que no me da el origen de error. llevo un par de horas buscarndo dicho error y no lo encuentro.
Tengo teorias de que el error me lo da el

*Mysqli_fetch.*

pero no se de que otra manera puedo imprimir los datos

```
 <?php
    include("coneccion.php");//Contiene la coneccion a la base de datos, funciona bien la estoy usando en otra parte de la pagina web.
    
    @$mostrar=$_POST['mostrar'];

    if($mostrar){
        $sql="select 'cedula', 'nombre', 'direccion', 'telefono' FROM 'cliente' ";
        $rsql= mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die (mysql_error());
        $sw=1;
    }
    
    /************Formulario*****************/
    echo"<form action=index.php#clients method=post>";       
    echo "<table id='tabla3'> <tr>";
        echo "<th>Cedula</th>";
        echo "<th>Nombre</th>";
        echo "<th>Direccion</th>";
        echo "<th>Telefono</th>";
        echo"<input type=submit name=mostrar value=Obtener Datos>";//Pulsa el boton para "generar tabla"
    echo "</tr>";
    echo"</table>";
    echo"</form>";
    if(@$sw>0){
        echo "<table id='tabla4'>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch($rsql)){
             echo"<tr>";
                echo "<td>";
                    echo $row['cedula'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>" ;
                    echo $row['nombre'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                    echo $row['direccion'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                    echo $row['telefono'];
                echo "</td>";
            echo"</tr>";
        }
        echo"</table>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Quitale el `@` a las variables y quitale las comillas simples `'` a las columnas y a la tabla.

Answer (score 2):

En tu sql tenes el nombre de la tabla entre comillas simples, eso da error, la query deberia tener mas esta forma:

```
SELECT 'cedula', 'nombre', 'direccion', 'telefono' FROM cliente;
```

De todas formas esa query devolvera los strings 'cedula', 'nombre', 'direccion', 'telefono' una vez por cada row de la tabla. 
Si queres que obtenga los datos de la tabla entonces deberias ponerlos como nomrbes de campos, i.e. sin comillas simples:

```
SELECT cedula, nombre, direccion, telefono FROM cliente;
```

Comment: adicional a eso debi poner mysqli_fetch_array para la impresion de Datos

Answer (score 0):

¿Has probado con [mysqli_fetch_row](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php)? esta función está diseñada para retornar un elemento iterable el cual recorrer dentro del while.